# How to get 3 values in one prompt using a special character to separate values to not write 3 prompts? javascript

Tags: javascript

I've recently started learning Javascript, have some small task where user enters 3 numbers and program chooses the smallest one. I can do it only using 3 prompts. Is there any way to make it in one prompt where user enters all 3 numbers?

```js
while (true) {
  var a, b, c;
  a = +prompt("enter a number");
  if (!a) {
    break;
  }
  b = +prompt("enter a number");
  if (!b) {
    break;
  }
  c = +prompt("enter a number");
  if (!c) {
    break;
  }
  var mimNumber = Math.min(a, b, c);
  alert("The smallest number is " + mimNumber);
}
```

Comment: If you are willing to accept solutions like using a special character to separate the values, just tell me and I reopen this question. However, if you are asking how to create 2 or more fields in one prompt, this is a duplicate, look at the link for the answers.

Comment: @user2314737 yes , I am willing to accept solution like using a special character to separate the values, thank you

Comment: Actually, you already have an answer (which is a mystery to me since I marked this question as a duplicate).

Comment: @AndyG edit the question according to your specifications so that it can be re-opened

Comment: No worries, I just reopened it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the user enter numbers which is then split and each element is compared with a variable to find the smallest number (starting with the first item in the newly created array. Then iterating over that array and comparing each item to the smallest number and if smaller - replacing the smallest number.

Note that I DO NOT recommend doing it this way - its just answering your question to be able to get the numbers in the one prompt and then get the smallest number from that. Also - this will break if the user enters numbers with any other delimiter than "," so this is NOT a good solution - it simply answers the question.

```js
var nums = prompt("enter 3 numbers separated by a comma");
var numArr = nums.split(',');
var minNum = parseInt(numArr[0]);

numArr.forEach(function (num) {
 let numb = parseInt(num);
 if(numb< minNum) { minNum = numb}
})
 
 alert("The smallest number is " + minNum);
```

Comment: @gavgrif Your answer doesn't work... I'll let you figure out why. Hint: `number != string`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - it does work - I jsut ran it and entered 6,3,2 and it corerctly identified 2 as the smallest number

Comment: Try `6,3,1111111`. Also, `sort` doesn't work like that.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - so amended - now smallestNum == GerardoFurtado

Comment: Now it's better. Here is a shorter version that you may want to use: https://jsfiddle.net/us4msqL2/

Answer (score 0):

Another copy of @gavgrif'sanswer just for showing a different approach.

```js
var numbers = prompt("enter 3 numbers separated by commas");
var smallest = Math.min.apply(null, numbers.split(',').map(Number));
alert("The smallest number is " + smallest);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove all not number symbols. Best way is to make it with RegExp

```
const initialText = '123, 32hfg54, 78';
const regExp = new RegExp("\\D");
const splittedArray = initialText.split(regExp).map(number => parseInt(number)).filter(number => Number.isInteger(number));
```

In result you will have number array in `splittedArray`. You should check that it is only 3 number in it (if needed) and find min number

```
if (splittedArray.length !== 3) {
    throw new Error('You should enter 3 number');
}
const minNumber = Math.min(...splittedArray);
```